# angular ngFor trackBy does not work as I expected

Tags: angular

When I read the doc (https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) for `ngFor` and `trackBy`, I thought I understood that Angular would only redo the DOM if the value returned by the trackBy function is changed, but when I played with it here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-bveczb), I found I actually don't understand it at all. Here's the essential part of my code:

```
export class AppComponent {
  data = [
    { id: 1, text: 'one' },
    { id: 2, text: 'two' },
    { id: 3, text: 'three' },
  ];

  toUpper() {
    this.data.map(d => d.text = d.text.toUpperCase());
  }

  trackByIds (index: number, item: any) {
    return item.id; 
  };
}
```

And:

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data; trackBy: trackByIds">
  {{ d.text }}
</div>
<button (click)=toUpper()>To Upper Case</button>
```

What I expected was clicking the button should **NOT** change the list from lower case to upper, but it did. I thought I used the `trackByIds` function for the `trackBy` in the `*ngFor`, and since the `trackByIds` only checks the `id` property of the items, so the change of anything other than id should not cause the DOM to be redone. I guess my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Having reread the doc link several times I think trackby is the answer to the question “should I add/remove/reorder nodes in the DOM?” when changes to data occur rather then should I reflect changes to node data.

Comment: tbh, in practice, trackBy is most relevant to lifecycle hooks of components within an ngFor.  The trackby function will determine when the init family of hooks will be re run, but change detection still always runs according to selected strategies. rendering != change detection.

Answer (score 17):

If `trackBy` doesn't seem to work:

#### 1) Make sure you are using the correct signature for the trackBy function

https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction

```
interface TrackByFunction<T> {
  (index: number, item: T): any
}
```

Your function **must take an index as the first parameter** even if you're only using the object to derive the 'tracked by' expression.

```
trackByProductSKU(_index: number, product: { sku: string })
{
    // add a breakpoint or debugger statement to be 100% sure your
    // function is actually being called (!)
    debugger;
    return product.sku;
}
```

#### 2) Make sure the **entire** control (that contains the *ngFor) isn't being redrawn, possibly as a side effect of something else.

- Add `<input/>` in the control  just above your `*ngFor` loop - (Yes - just an empty text box)
- Load the page and type something into each of the textboxes (I usually just enter 1, 2, 3, 4...)
- Add / remove an item from the list - or whatever you need to do to trigger a change
- If the contents of your textbox disappears then it means you're redrawing the entire container control (in other words your `trackBy` has nothing to do with your underlying issue).
- You can put `<input/>` at each 'level' if you have multiple nested loops. Just type a value into each box, then see which values are retained when you perform whatever action is causing the problem.

#### 3) Make sure the `trackBy` function is returning a unique value for each row:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of lineItems; trackBy: trackByProductSKU">

    <input />
    Tracking value: [{{ trackByProductSKU(-1, item) }}]
</li>
```

Display the track by value inside your loop like this. This will eliminate any stupid mistakes - such as getting the name or casing of the track by property incorrect. The empty `input` element is deliberate

If everything is working properly you should be able to type in each input box, trigger a change in the list and it shouldn't lose the value you type.

#### 4) If you cannot determine a unique value, just return the item itself. This is the default behavior (from `trackByIdentity`) if you don't specify a trackBy function.

```
// angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_iterable_differ.ts

const trackByIdentity = (index: number, item: any) => item;

export class DefaultIterableDiffer<V> implements IterableDiffer<V>, IterableChanges<V> {

 constructor(trackByFn?: TrackByFunction<V>) {
    this._trackByFn = trackByFn || trackByIdentity;
 }
```

#### 5) Don't accidentally return null or undefined!

Let's say you're using `product: { sku: string }` as your trackBy function and for whatever reason the products no longer have that property set. (Maybe it changed to `SKU` or has an extra level.)

If you return `product.sku` from your function and it's null then you're going to get some unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 10):

The `trackBy` function determines when a div element created by the `ngFor` loop should be re-rendered (replaced by a new element in the DOM). Please note that Angular can always update an element on change detection by modifying its properties or attributes. Updating an element does not imply replacing it by a new one. That is why setting the text to uppercase is reflected in the browser, even when the div elements are not re-rendered.

By default,  without specifying a `trackBy` function, a div element will be re-rendered when the corresponding item value changes. In the present case, that would be when the `data` array item is replaced by a different object (the item "value" being the object reference); for example after executing the following method:

```
recreateDataArray() {
  this.data = this.data.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
}
```

Now, with a `trackBy` function that returns the data item `id`, you tell the `ngFor` loop to re-render the div element when the `id` property of the corresponding item changes. Therefore, the existing div elements would remain in the DOM after executing the `recreateDataArray` method above, but they would be replaced by new ones after running the following method:

```
incrementIds() {
  this.data.forEach(x => { x.id += 10; });
}
```

You can experiment with [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-bl3tod?file=app/app.component.html). A checkbox allows to turn on/off the `trackByIds` logic, and a console message indicates when the div elements have been re-rendered. The "Set Red Text" button changes the style of the DOM elements directly; you know that red div elements have been re-rendered when their content turns to black.

Answer (score 0):

trackBy is actually used to prevent rerendering of same element in the DOM again and again. It cannot be used like you're using. Let me elaborate. If you got array like:

```
data = [
{ id: 1, text: 'one' },
{ id: 2, text: 'two' },
{ id: 3, text: 'three' },


];
```

And on click of button you change the array somewhat like:

```
  changeArray() {


this.data = [
    { id: 1, text: 'one' },
    { id: 2, text: 'two' },
    { id: 3, text: 'three' },
    { id: 4, text: 'four' },
    { id: 5, text: 'five' },
  ];
  }

trackByIds (index: number, item: any) {
return item.id; 
  };
}
```

And:

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data; trackBy: trackByIds">
  {{ d.text }}
</div>
<button (click)="changeArray()>Change Array</button>
```

When you call changeArray() on click of button. Then, trackBy guarantees that only items having new id will be added to DOM and previous one's will not be rerendered i.e. items having id 1-3 wil not be rendered again in DOM. If you think you can use it to prevent manipulations, then you're wrong. Hope you get me!
Proof:
Before button click
[image: Before changeArray clicked]
After button click, only highlighted content changes

[image: After button click only four and five shown highlighted as they're only change]

If one is converted to ONE using click of button
[image: Proof if one is converted to ONE]

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question.

Comment: I mistakenly posted incompleted answer, sorry for that. You should recheck now.

Comment: I didn’t downvote, plus I still don’t think you’ve read the question properly which is why does in place change to data that does not affect track by function still cause rerender.

Comment: If in the new data you change the text from 'one' to 'ONE', would it re-render the first item?

Comment: Yes, because it is change in value of current id

Comment: I have added the proof!